# How to get unique values from a filtered table through VBA?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, filtering

I have a table that is being filtered through slicers which the user can fiddle around on their own. For example, say I have a table with 4 columns and after the user selects which filters he or she wants to apply on each column through the respective slicers, we have the following table:

```
Client ID | Identifier | Gender | Occupation
123       | A          | F      | 1
999       | Z          | M      | 5
563       | B          | F      | 5
```

How do I get the unique values for each filtered column? In particular, I want 123, 999 and 563 for `Client ID`, A, Z and B for `Identifier`, M and F for `Gender` and 1 and 5 for `Occupation`.

Note that I should only have one 'F' for `Gender` instead of two and one '5' for `Occupation` instead of two.

The reason for this is because I need to turn the above information into a `WHERE` condition for SQL Server 2016. Using the above example, I want the end result to be `AND [Client ID] IN ('123, '999', '563') AND [Identifier] IN ('A', 'Z', 'B') AND [Gender] IN ('F', 'M') AND [Occupation] IN ('1', '5')`. This will be stored in a variable in VBA.

Note also that the rows in the filtered table may not be contiguous due to the filters and the number of columns should be dynamic.

Comment: you can use a dictionary per slicer to store unique values only: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Comment: What do you have in mind when you say **unique**? I cannot see anything not being unique in the table you show (filtered, probably.)... Do the client ID repeat on the filtered area? If so, probably more values corresponding to the other three columns will exist. How to deal with them? To take only the last/first combination, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetUniqList()
    Dim rArea As Range, visRng As Range
    Dim sKey As String, c As Range, i As Long
    Dim arrDic(1 To 4)
    For i = 1 To 4
        Set arrDic(i) = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Next
    Set visRng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Not visRng Is Nothing Then
        For Each rArea In visRng.Areas
            For Each c In rArea.Rows
                For i = 1 To 4
                    sKey = "'" & c.Cells(i).Value & "'"
                    If Not arrDic(i).exists(sKey) Then arrDic(i)(sKey) = ""
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End If
    For i = 1 To 4
        Debug.Print Join(arrDic(i).Keys, ",")
    Next
End Sub
```

Test data:

[image]

Output:

```
'A','C'
'1','2'
'AA','CC','FF'
'S1','S3','S4','S6'
```

---

*Update:*

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetUniqList()
    Dim rArea As Range, visRng As Range, sSQL As String
    Dim sKey As String, c As Range, i As Long, oTab As ListObject
    Dim arrDic(), ColCnt As Long, headerRng As Range
    Const SQL = "[@@] IN (##)"
    Set oTab = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    Set visRng = oTab.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set headerRng = oTab.HeaderRowRange
    ColCnt = visRng.Columns.Count
    ReDim arrDic(1 To ColCnt)
    For i = 1 To ColCnt
        Set arrDic(i) = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Next
    If Not visRng Is Nothing Then
        For Each rArea In visRng.Areas
            For Each c In rArea.Rows
                For i = 1 To ColCnt
                    sKey = "'" & c.Cells(i).Value & "'"
                    If Not arrDic(i).exists(sKey) Then arrDic(i)(sKey) = ""
                Next
            Next
        Next
        For i = 1 To ColCnt
            sSQL = Replace(Replace(SQL, "@@", headerRng(i)), "##", Join(arrDic(i).Keys, ","))
            Debug.Print sSQL
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Output:

```
[Column1] IN ('A','C')
[Column2] IN ('1','2')
[Column3] IN ('AA','CC','FF')
[Column4] IN ('S1','S3','S4','S6')
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for this! It largely gives what I need! I just have two queries. Firstly, where is `oTab` being used? Secondly, is it possible to use the keys in `arrDic(i)` as strings? Because I ultimate want to append the column names to each of the keys. For example, I want `[Column1] IN ('A','C')`. I tried `dim temp as string, temp = "[Column1] IN (" & Join(arrDic(1).keys, ",") & ")"`, but got an error that says "out of range".

Comment: I've updated the code.

Comment: Thanks! Also, what if I need to create a dynamic number of `arrDics` based on the number of columns I have, which could change? In the example, it is 4, but could be any number. in reality (though usually its a small number). I tried `Dim ColumnCount As Integer, ColumnCount = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`. I could replace all the '4's in your code with `ColumnCount`, except for the '4' in `Dim arrDic(1 To 4)`. When I did that, I get an error that says "constant expression required".

Comment: Please specify the requirement all at once.

Comment: My apologies as the changes come to my mind when I run your code and test it out for myself. Making the number of dictionaries dynamic should be the last requirement!

Comment: The number of dictionaries, field name, table (listobject) location are dynamic.